# ui accordion with tinyscrollbar

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to combine jquery accordion with tiny scrollbar. Is there a way for the scrollbar to be updated when a accordion item appears or collapses? here is what I did so far with no success (I get an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function') when I trigger the function:

```
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#accordion-main-[[+idx]]').accordion({
    collapsible:true,
    active:false,
    heightStyle:"content",
    autoHeight: false,
    activate: function(event, ui) {
     //alert('complete');
     jQuery('#scrollbar-[[+idx]]').tinyscrollbar_update();
    }
    });

  });`
```

Comment: not sure if it just a mistake but try removing the wrapping quotes

Comment: what quotes do you mean? I forgot to notice that it is in modX installation.